# How to pass a file path provided in python code to a vbscript which will be run by that python code?

Tags: python, vbscript

I have a running vbscript which asks user for path. Now, I want to perform certain RPA tasks using python followed by running that vbscript.Using Python, user will get the prompt to provide path of that excel file. Now, my query is how can I pass that path stored in python code to vbscript?

Comment: I want to run vbscript from python and I will provide path of another excel input file in python which needs to be passed to the vbscript.I am a windows7 user.

Comment: It is madness to run all these programs. If one program can do something then probably all can. Python can do excel just as well as VBSCript.

Answer (score -1):

You should have a look at the win32com.client. I'm gonna leave an answer here to help you going. Try to run it, google the errors.

```
import win32com.client

excel = win32com.client.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
excel.Visible = False
wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(xlfile) # path to excel here
excel.Run("Main.RunMain", arg1) # arg here , (Main.RunMain > module+sub)
wb.Close()

del excel
```

Comment: This is not my query. I can provide excel file path in python. But I don't know how to pass this excel input file path to vbscript. This excel input file will actually be used by vbscript and I am just providing it's path in python code.

Comment: The intention is that you put your path to excel (xlfile) and you put the name of your vbscript (Main.RunMain) and then pass the argument, the link (arg1).